# Javascript, access to variables of other window

Tags: javascript, window

I have to make a web page with two different window and let they share some variables.

When the main window is loaded, the second windows is opened, and here I can store the second window object and access its vars:

**Main window**

```
var mainvar=1;
var secondwindow=open('second.htm');
$("button").click(function(){
    alert(secondwindow.testvar);
});
```

My trouble starts when I want to do the oppsite: access main window vars from the second window script:

**Second window**

```
var secondvar=2;
var mainwindow;// how can I set this?
$("bunno").click(function(){
   alert(mainwindow.testvar);
});
```

Comment: When you say window, do you mean browser tab?

Comment: not sure it will work, but how about putting in the main window: `secondwindow.mainwindow = window` ?

Comment: @PierreDuc was not a bad idea but it doesn't work, maybe it must be set in a timer or onload event of the second window....

Comment: @Tobia try to set it in the button click event :) you are sure it will be loaded by then

Comment: @Bata I mean window (javascript object), can be a window, tab or popup.

Comment: As far as I have experienced the main window can be accessed from second window with window.opener.variable

Comment: @TonyDuffill if this is cross-browser property, this is the better answer!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the variables and make them accessible between windows and sessions.

```
localStorage.setItem('myValue', '1234');//in window 1
alert(localstorage.myValue)//in window 2
```

Failing that, [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) could also be used. Not quite as secure, but if you aren't passing secure data between the windows, this would work too.

Answer (score 1):

I found this that maybe can fit:

**Main window**

```
var mainvar=1;
var secondwindow=open('second.htm');
$("button").click(function(){
    alert(secondwindow.testvar);
});
$(secondwindow).load(function() {
    secondwindow.mainwindow=window;
});
```

**Second window**

```
var secondvar=2;
var mainwindow=false;
$("bunno").click(function(){
   alert(mainwindow.testvar);
});
```

Comment: very nice approach